# Quicktime 7 on Delphi 7

Tags: delphi, video, delphi-7, quicktime

Is it possible to play/control Quicktime 7 movies in Delphi 7?

I would need to control the play direction (forward/backward) and displayed tracks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes, by using Apple QuickTime ActiveX 2.0.

here you have how to import an Active X into Delphi

http://delphi.about.com/library/howto/htaddactivex.htm

and here you have a component

http://www.sourcecodeonline.com/details/quicktime_movie.html

or by using Jedi http://www.delphi-jedi.org/jedi-quicktime.html

Answer (score 1):

did you check [JEDI Quicktime Project](http://www.delphi-jedi.org/jedi-quicktime.html)